# CSS not working right when using Do Loop in bootstrap modal in rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, loops

I'm trying to make product images appear as a carousel in a `bootstrap modal` window.

As the code is now I'm only able to see the first image. At the moment there are three images for this product, uploaded with active admin.

I have tried `else` `elsif` and  `index ==1`for the `else`. I have also tried other modification of in the code below.

I'm kind of stuck, can anyone take a look at this and advise me?

** UPDATE see context in comments from @Lucas Costa**

the problem I'm experiencing seems to be because of the `CSS`, most probably the `.carousel-inner`

Have anyone ever had similar problem?

```
 <div class="container text-center">

   <h1> Click Me </h1>
    <!-- Large modal -->
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>

    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

   <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <% @product.photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <% if index == 0 %>
    <div class="item active">
     <%= image_tag(photo.image.url(:large), class: 'img-responsive') %>
    </div>
    <% elsif index == 1 %>
    <div class="item">
     <%= image_tag(photo.image.url(:large), class: 'img-responsive') %>
  </div>
  <% else index == 2%>
   <div class="item">
     <%= image_tag(photo.image.url(:large), class: 'img-responsive') %>
   </div>
  <% end %>
 </div>
<% end %>



 <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends what you want.

**option 1:** you just want to handle the first case (note that here I'm using `else`)

```
<% @product.photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <% if index == 0 %>
      <div class="item active">
        <%= image_tag(photo.image.url(:large), class: 'img-responsive') %>
      </div>
    <% else %>
      <div class="item">
        <%= image_tag(photo.image.url(:large), class: 'img-responsive') %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**option 2:** you want to handle the first and the second case (note that here I'm using `elsif` and `else`)

```
<% @product.photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <% if index == 0 %>
      <div class="item active">
        <%= image_tag(photo.image.url(:large), class: 'img-responsive') %>
      </div>
    <% elsif index == 1 %>
      <div class="item">
        <%= image_tag(photo.image.url(:large), class: 'img-responsive') %>
      </div>
    <% else %>
      <%# Your other code here %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but both options gives the same result, I'm only seeing the first image `index ==0` in both options. I'm not able to select between images in the carousel

Comment: Are you sure that the problem resides in the `for` loop? Can you see all the images in HTML (using the Chrome inspector, for instance)?

Comment: Yes the images are there, I can see them by using this code on the same page `<% @product.photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>    
      <div class="row">
      <% if index == 0 %>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 center-block">

         <%= image_tag(photo.image.url(:large)) %>                    
        </div>
      <% else %>
      <div class=" col-md-6 col-xs-12 center-block">
        <%= image_tag(photo.image.url(:thumb)) %>   
        </div>
      <% end %>
     <% end %>
    
  </div>`

Comment: Any chance of having some weird CSS style being applied to the `carousel-inner` or `item` class? The fact of the code without these classes has work makes me believe that the problem isn't in the `for` loop

Comment: well I haven't modified any CSS style yet for this. But if I remove the `.item` or the `.carosuel-inner` I see all three images piled up on each other.  So could that be a `bootstrap`problem?

Comment: Are you using the [official bootstrap gem for Rails](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)? Maybe is just a configuration problem, a missing import or other stuff like that.

Comment: I'm using this setup in the `gemfile`                                                            `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'`   this is the setup I've always used

Answer (score 0):

Ok, by looking at your code the problem seems to be in the first lines of the `<!-- Wrapper for slides -->`

you are writing it like

```
 <% @product.photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
```

but it should be

```
 <div class="carousel-inner">
  <% @product.photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
```

Otherwise the loop is inserting `.carousel-inner` to every image and that breaks the Carousel.

Just switch those two lines and it should work. And remember to also switch the `</div>` and the `<% end %>` at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you so much @DaudiHell this did the trick for me, now it is working like a charm :(

Comment: No problem, glad to help